# Property 'Choices' does not exist on type 'Promise<IFieldInfo>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx, pnp-js

I have the following type script inside my ReactJs SPFx sharepoint online web part:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  IPropertyPaneDropdownOption,
  PropertyPaneDropdown} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'ContactListWebPartStrings';
import ContactListApp from './components/ContactListApp';
import { IContactListProps } from './components/IContactListProps';
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";


export interface IContactListWebPartProps {
  department: string;
}

export default class ContactListWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IContactListWebPartProps> {
  private viewModeOptions: IPropertyPaneDropdownOption[] = null;
  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IContactListProps> = React.createElement(
      ContactListApp,
      {
        department: this.properties.department,
        context: this.context
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return super.onInit().then( _ => {
      sp.setup({
        spfxContext: this.context
      });
      const choice =  
      sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Contacts').fields.getByTitle('Department').get();
      this.viewModeOptions = choice.Choices.map((choice: string, idx: number) => 
      {
        return {
         key: idx,
         text: choice
        }
      })
   });
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneDropdown('department', {
                  label: 'Department',
                  options: this.viewModeOptions,
                  selectedKey: this.viewModeOptions[0].key,
                  disabled: !this.viewModeOptions
                 }),
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

but i am getting this error on `choice.Choices.map`:-

> Property 'Choices' does not exist on type 'Promise'

Comment: Seems like the promise is not resolved. You can't map through a promise, you have to map through what the resolved promise returns.

Comment: @Mr.Robot thanks for the reply... so can you mention what i need to do? i am not an expert in React nor TS.. thanks in advance for nay help

Comment: Sure, instead of `const choice =  sp.web.lists.getByTitle...`, try `sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Contacts').fields.getByTitle('Department').get().then((choice) => { console.log(choice) // what is this <<< this.viewModeOptions = choice.Choices.map((choice: string, idx: number) => ({ key: idx, text: choice})})` apologies for the formatting

Comment: @Mr.Robot thanks for the code.. but what do u mean by `what is this` inside the code?

Comment: Ahh I've just added the console.log() so you should be able to log / "see" what `choice` is

Comment: @Mr.Robot it will be empty

Comment: Use this version of sp: "@pnp/common": "^1.3.10",
"@pnp/logging": "^1.3.10",
"@pnp/odata": "^1.3.10",
"@pnp/polyfill-ie11": "^1.0.2",
"@pnp/sp": "^1.3.10",
"@pnp/sp-clientsvc": "^1.3.10",

Comment: The only problem could be that Internal Name (not Title) of list or field is different from "Contacts" or "Department"

Comment: Och lol Apology (during formatting) - const choice =  sp.web.lists.getByTitle must be const choice = await      sp.web.lists.getByTitle !

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```js
const choice = sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Contacts').fields.getByTitle('Department').get();
```

(In this case choice is just Promise, not returned value.)

For this:

```js
const choice =  await sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Contacts').fields.getByTitle('Department').get();
```

(In this case await cause to load data and choice contains value.)

With await inside function, you need to make it async like this:

```
return super.onInit().then(async _ => {
```